# React native flex layout with VictoryChart, Chart fit the parent container

Tags: layout, flexbox, react-native, victory-charts

I have the following render function:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text> Header
                </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.services}>
                <Text>Services</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.chart}>

                <VictoryChart>
                    <VictoryLine
                        style={{
                            data: {stroke: "#c43a31"},
                            parent: {border: "1px solid #ccc"}
                        }}
                        data={[
                            {x: 1, y: 2},
                            {x: 2, y: 3},
                            {x: 3, y: 5},
                            {x: 4, y: 4},
                            {x: 5, y: 7}
                        ]}
                    />
                </VictoryChart>    
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I have some sort of chart in the bottom section of page, But I cannot force the chart to fill the its parent, It kind of overflows from its dedicated section, How can I achieve this?(I tried to use `flexWrap` but it is no help !)

Here is the preview of what it looks like now:
[image]

And here is my style sheet for this simple design:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    header: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#e7fe52'
    },

    services: {
        flex: 4,
        backgroundColor: '#20fe23'
    },

    chart: {
        flex: 2,
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        backgroundColor: '#4fccb0'
    }
});
```

Comment: which library are you using for VictoryChart?

Comment: @HaiderAli https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native

Comment: How about transform its fixed parent to grandparent? Maybe it will be blur

Comment: I guess I did that too, I will give it a try if I get my hand on my PC.

Answer (score 8):

VictoryChart seems to have a default height of 300 and it doesn't adapt to its parent height. So, one way to solve this would be to remove the flex: 2 attribute from the chart style and add manually calculated dimensions. Something like this:

```
const chartHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.3;
const chartWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;

<VictoryChart height={chartHeight} width={chartWidth} >
    <VictoryLine
        style={{
            data: {stroke: "#c43a31"},
            parent: {border: "1px solid #ccc"}
        }}
        data={[
            {x: 1, y: 2},
            {x: 2, y: 3},
            {x: 3, y: 5},
            {x: 4, y: 4},
            {x: 5, y: 7}
        ]}
    />
</VictoryChart>

// styles  
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    header: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#e7fe52'
    },
    services: {
        flex: 4,
        backgroundColor: '#20fe23'
    },
    chart: {
        //remove flex from here
        backgroundColor: '#4fccb0'
    }
});
```

Although this is not perfect it works, but I would set a minimum height for the chart. I mean if the available space is too small, it won't look nice. 
In this case you could wrap your screen inside a ScrollView.

Comment: I am coming to realization that the design I want is not very conventional, I am new to mobile development. maybe I am mixing web dev with mobile and in mobile everything should be fixed !

Comment: For me the strange thing in your layout is that the chart (which is an important and impressive element of your screen) is at the bottom of the screen and it feels like you're trying to squeeze it there to accommodate all screen sizes. Elements don't have to be fixed on mobile, you can use ScrollView when you have to :). Just decide a height that makes your chart look good and let it scroll on short height devices.

Comment: sounds fare, this is not the actual design, I just wanted to start a simple project to see how hard it is to do a project in RN (we have web development background) and this experience was not successful : ))

Comment: You should give it another chance :) It's not perfect, but when you get the hang of it you realise it is pretty impressive. I'm also a web dev and struggled at first, but I can't find a similar framework that can produce native iOS and android apps with a shared codebase...

Answer (score -1):

each flex container is one flex try to divide your component into 1

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    header: {
        flex: 0.15,
        backgroundColor: '#e7fe52'
    },

    services: {
        flex: 0.5,
        backgroundColor: '#20fe23'
    },

    chart: {
        flex: 0.35,
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        backgroundColor: '#4fccb0'
    }
});
```

0.15 + 0.5 + 0.35 = 1

Comment: The problem is that the chart has a fixed height regardless of its parent, if a parent hieght is less than 300, it doesn't scale

Comment: this answer is falsy by all means